# Joins and subquerying in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume a table transaction that has attributes: mid, symbol

Assumed data

```
mid symbol
1   b
2   b
3   c
4   b
5   e
2   e
1   e
```

The question demands to find mid's who have all symbol's that are with mid=2

Comment: So the output will be `1,2,4,5,2,1`?

Comment: No for the above eg:- the symbols for mid =2 is b and e
and only other member that has both b and e is 1

so output should be 1

Comment: Do i need to elaborate more?

Comment: Include the desired output in your question. Explain the rules to derive at the output.

Comment: In case mid=2 has two rows with symbol f, are two f rows also required for a mid to be returned?

Comment: no one f row should be enough @ jarlh

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I am not sure about ORACLE, but I think it should work.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( mid INT, symbol CHAR(1) )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 'b' ),
        ( 2, 'b' ),
        ( 3, 'c' ),
        ( 4, 'b' ),
        ( 5, 'e' ),
        ( 2, 'e' ),
        ( 1, 'e' )

SELECT DISTINCT
        t2.mid
FROM    @t t1
        JOIN @t t2 ON t2.symbol = t1.symbol
WHERE   t1.mid = 2
GROUP BY t2.mid
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT ( t2.symbol )) = ( SELECT    COUNT(DISTINCT symbol)
                                          FROM      @t
                                          WHERE     mid = 2
                                        )
ORDER BY t2.mid
```

Output:

```
mid
1
2
```

If you don't want mid=2 in output just change
`WHERE   t1.mid = 2` to
`WHERE   t1.mid = 2 AND t2.mid <> 2`

But I want to mention that this query will also return such mids whose set of symbols consists of a set of mid=2 and may be some other values.

Comment: Whats wrong with the question for me to be down-voted?

Answer (score 0):

Try NB when you have more symbols in the data assuming you want mids common to all need a more sophisticated approach. Needs adapting for Oracle

```
select 1 as mid,   'b' as Symbol into #Data
union all
select 2,   'b'
union all
select 3,   'c'
union all
select 4,   'b'
union all
select 5,   'e'
union all
select 2 ,  'e'
union all
select 1,   'e'

select D.Mid
From
(select B.Mid, B.Symbol
From #Data B
inner join (select Symbol
from #Data
where mid = 2) A on B.Symbol = A.Symbol) C
inner join 
(select B.Mid, B.Symbol
From #Data B
inner join (select Symbol
from #Data
where mid = 2) A on B.Symbol = A.Symbol) D On D.Mid = C.Mid and D.Symbol <> C.Symbol
inner join
(select B.Mid, COUNT(Distinct B.Symbol) as SC
From #Data B
inner join (select Symbol
from #Data
where mid = 2) A on B.Symbol = A.Symbol
Group By B.Mid) E ON C.Mid = E.Mid
inner join
(select B.Mid, COUNT(Distinct B.Symbol) as SC
From #Data B
inner join (select Symbol
from #Data
where mid = 2) A on B.Symbol = A.Symbol
Group By B.Mid) F ON D.Mid = F.Mid
Where D.Mid <> 2 and E.SC = F.SC
Group by D.Mid
```

Answer (score 0):

The innermost subquery returns all symbols for the main-query's mid. The not exists makes sure no mid = 2 symbol is missing.

```
select * from table t1
where not exists (select 1 from table
                  where mid = 2
                  and symbol not in (select symbol from table t2
                                     where t1.mid = t2.mid
                                       and symbol is not null))
```

Comment: can you take the principle and convert it to SQL that Oracle accepts?

Comment: This doesn't answer to what OP's requirement as explained by him in the comments.

Comment: Sorry, missed the all requirement (read any). Will edit later.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE TAB1 AS
SELECT 1 MID,'b' SYMBOL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 MID,'b' SYMBOL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 MID,'c' SYMBOL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4 MID,'b' SYMBOL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5 MID,'e' SYMBOL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 MID,'e' SYMBOL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1 MID,'e' SYMBOL FROM DUAL;
```

First get all distinct symbols where mid=2.  Add count of distinct symbols for mid=2 (using cross join).  Join these symbols to all symbols of non-2-mids.  Group by mid and mid-2-symbol-count, and only pick mids which matched on at least mid-2-symbol-count symbols (or exactly mid-2-symbol-count symbols, see trailing comment)

```
SELECT MID
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT SYMBOL FROM TAB1 WHERE MID=2)
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SYMBOL) C FROM TAB1 WHERE MID=2)
NATURAL JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT MID, SYMBOL FROM TAB1 WHERE MID <> 2)
GROUP BY MID, C 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SYMBOL) >= C;
```

...change `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SYMBOL) >= C` to `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SYMBOL) = C` if you want mids with exactly same symbols as mid=2, and no others.

Edit: if (MID,SYMBOL) is a unique key, then you can drop all "DISTINCT" keywords from the solution.  If (MID,SYMBOL) is not unique, *and* you need to return MIDs that match all occurences of each symbol of mid=2 (so, if (2, 'b') occurs twice, mid=1 would only qualify if (1,'b') occurred at least twice), then SQL would be:

```
SELECT MID
FROM
    (SELECT SYMBOL, COUNT(*) SYMBOL_COUNT1 FROM TAB1 WHERE MID=2
     GROUP BY SYMBOL)
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SYMBOL) C FROM TAB1 WHERE MID=2)
NATURAL JOIN
    (SELECT MID, SYMBOL, COUNT(*) SYMBOL_COUNT2 
     FROM TAB1 WHERE MID <> 2
     GROUP BY MID, SYMBOL)
WHERE SYMBOL_COUNT2 >= SYMBOL_COUNT1
GROUP BY MID, C 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SYMBOL) >= C;
```

...in this case, changing `SYMBOL_COUNT2 >= SYMBOL_COUNT1` to `SYMBOL_COUNT2 = SYMBOL_COUNT1` would limit results to those mids with exactly same number of occurences of each symbol; so if (2,'b') occurred twice and (1,'b') occurred 3 or more times, 1 would be excluded.